# urls generated by CMenu and CBreadcrumbs contain percent encoded characters

Tags: url, yii

When I create a link from a CMenu or CBreadcrumb, the parameters are surrounded by percent encoded characters. This causes an invalid request error.

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'View partner', 'url'=>array('partner/view/', array('id'=>1337))),
);
```

Generates

```
index.php?r=partner/view&0%5Bid%5D=1337
```

Which is the percent encoded equivalent of

```
index.php?r=partner/view&0[id]=1337

$this->createUrl('partner/view/', array('id'=>1337)));
```

Generates

```
index.php?r=partner/view&id=1337
```

which is correct. How can I fix this?

I use Yii 1.1.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the passed url is in the wrong format. Per the [CHtml:normalizeUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail) docs, it should be something like this:

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'View partner', 'url'=>array('partner/view/', 'id'=>1337)),
);
```